Question regarding how the Beis Yosef understands the Rosh with regards to the required size of the Esrog
The Beis Yosef on the Tur (Orach Chaim 656) writes that when the Rosh (Bava Kama 1:7) uses the term ״כאגוז״ (the size of a wallnut) when describing the required size of the Esrog, that the Rosh is referring to Rabbi Meir’s opinion, but according to Rabbi Yehuda, the required size is that of an egg, and therefore when the Gemara (Bava Kama 9a) says that a Mitzvah-article should be bigger than the required size if possible, according to Rabbi Yehuda it should be bigger than an egg.
My question is: the Rosh (Sukkah 3:15) seems to accept that the size of an egg is not essentially the required size of the Esrog, and the only reason it needs to be that size is because an Esrog that is less than that size is considered unripe, but essentially the required size is that it should be big enough that it should be noticeable when held in one’s hand.
Based on that, why does the Beis Yosef explain the Rosh, that when the Gemara says that the Mitzvah-article should be bigger than the required size if possible, that according to Rabbi Yehuda it should be bigger than an egg - but doesn’t the Rosh say that the actual required size of the Esrog is as long as it is visible?

There is no opinion in Gemara that says the esrog has to be visible.  It is either R. Meir or R. Yehuda. To be visible - is the extra hidur that Rosh adds upon the gemara.
